# ERROR 1526 (HY000): Table has no partition for value 1426566990

Tags: mysql

my mysql server can not partition:

mysql server version is : 5.1.71-log

OS : CentOS 6.5 x64

```
mysql>show create table 
| history | CREATE TABLE `history` (
`itemid` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
`clock` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`value` double(16,4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.0000',
`ns` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
KEY `history_1` (`itemid`,`clock`) USING BTREE
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 |


mysql>select * from history limit 11;
+--------+------------+--------------+-----------+
| itemid | clock      | value        | ns        |
+--------+------------+--------------+-----------+
|  35210 | 1426566411 |  189626.1400 | 856563617 |
|  35211 | 1426566414 |  328805.1900 |   3954734 |
|  35231 | 1426566432 |  497665.5600 | 124983500 |
|  35232 | 1426566433 |  839002.1200 |  66033134 |
|  35252 | 1426566453 |  175085.9200 |  58097601 |
|  35253 | 1426566454 |  113664.0000 | 104347387 |
|  35273 | 1426566474 |   11188.8300 |  95493093 |
|  35274 | 1426566475 |   12394.8100 | 109145645 |
|  35168 | 1426566969 | 2793042.2500 | 919270427 |
|  35169 | 1426566970 | 1148138.7500 | 649565410 |
|  35189 | 1426566990 |   65273.8800 | 718286083 |
+--------+------------+--------------+-----------+
11 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> alter table history partition by range (clock)(partition p1 values less than(1426566990));
ERROR 1526 (HY000): Table has no partition for value 1426566990
```

But, the value already in the table, why the error occurs?

Who can help me?

Comment: Is it necessary for you to use exactly `1426566990` value for partitioning? If you want partition that covers all rows, `MAXVALUE` can be used.

Comment: thanks,if I use the 'MAXVALUE' value,it have only one partition,I don't know the second partition how to create or add

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that server does not know where to place a row with value `1426566990`. The `less than` condition is not inclusive. That means you should use `less than(1426566991)` in order to make this working. But if you decide to add a new row with value more than or equals to `1426566991`, you'll get the same error. Therefore, I recommend the following approach:

```
alter table history partition by range (clock)(partition p1 values less than MAXVALUE);
```

More about range partitioning: [RANGE Partitioning](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/partitioning-range.html). There is an example for your case:

> <...> Under this scheme, there is no rule that covers a row whose store_id is greater than 20, so an error results because the server does not know where to place it.

Comment: thanks.
my history table have 100 records,I think that every 10 records in a partition.
report this error when I partition the first partition.

Comment: mysql> alter table history partition by range (clock)(partition Pmax values less than(MAXVALUE));
    Query OK, 100 rows affected (0.00 sec)
    Records: 100  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

this is ok,the same error appear when i create the second partition

Comment: such as : mysql> alter table history partition by range (clock)(partition P1 values less than(1426566990));
ERROR 1526 (HY000): Table has no partition for value 1426566990

Comment: @noback try to create partitions in a single statement: `alter table history partition by range (clock)(partition P1 values less than(1426566990), partition Pmax values less than MAXVALUE)`

Comment: I think that less than the value 1426566990 is top 10 value,why mysql server does not know?

Comment: thank you very much.I had understood.first of all,I create the first partition such as : alter table history partition by range (clock)(partition Pmax values less than(MAXVALUE));when i think to create the second partition,i execute such as : alter table history partition by range (clock)(partition p1 values less than(1426566990),partition pmax values less than(MAXVALUE));

Comment: by parity of reasoning,the third partition such as : alter table history partition by range (clock)(partition p1 values less than(1426566990),partition p2 values less than(1426567095),partition pmax values less than(MAXVALUE));that is right?

Comment: @noback 1. I am not sure about performance: it is likely that is repartitioning is a costly operation, and 2. In the last example reorder conditions, because `1426567095 < 1426566990`. I am not sure whether MySQL allows inverting conditions or not, but your code definitely will be more clear.

Comment: @noback if my answer has solved your issue, please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to me and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Comment: 1426567095 < 1426566990 is not right? be meant to 1426567095 > 1426566990

Answer (score 1):

@Xokker

:)

how to extend the partition later on.

I try to use follow code:

```
alter table history add partition(partition p3 values less than (1426567221));
ERROR 1481 (HY000): MAXVALUE can only be used in last partition definition
```

have other method to extentd the partition,have not effect the DB performance?